# docker compose and gitlab ci/cd running django : connection refused

Tags: docker, gitlab

This is my gitlab-ci.yml:

```
stages:
  - build

variables:   
  DOCKER_HOST: tcp://docker:2375/   
  DOCKER_DRIVER: overlay2

e2e:   
  stage: build   
  image: "docker/compose:latest"   
  services:
    - docker:dind   
  environment:
    name: preproduction   
  before_script:
    - grep -v '^#' $VARENV_FILE > test_env_file
    - grep -v '^#' $VARFILE_POSTGRES >> test_env_file
    - docker version
    - docker-compose version   
  script:
    - set -e
    - docker network create test_network
    - docker-compose up -d react
    - docker exec -t react node -v
    - docker exec -t react npm -v
    - docker exec -t react yarn -v
    - docker-compose up -d backend # run pip install -r requirements.txt
    - docker exec -t backend python --version
    - docker exec -t backend python -m django --version
    - docker exec -t backend python manage.py collectstatic --noinput
    #- docker exec -t backend python manage.py makemigrations --lint
    #- docker exec -t backend python manage.py check --deploy
    - docker exec -td backend python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:3000
    - docker exec -t react ping backend -c 4
    - docker exec -t backend curl http://127.0.0.1:3000
    - docker exec -t react curl http://backend:3000
    - docker exec -t react yarn run tests
    - docker-compose down   except:
    - tags
    - master
```

The docker-compose file is as follow:

```
---
version: '3.7'
 
services:
  backend:
    container_name: backend
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./django_docker_build_for_test/django/Dockerfile
    image: solene
    volumes:
      - frontend:/app/frontend
    env_file:
      - ./test_env_file
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
  react:
    container_name: react
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./django_docker_build_for_test/react/Dockerfile
    image: react
    volumes:
      - frontend:/app/frontend #react container à lancer en premier pour avoir son contenu dans le volume partagé
    env_file:
      - ./test_env_file
volumes: 
  frontend:
```

The ping command works.

But the curl http://127.0.0.1:3000 and curl http://backend:3000 dont work : i get 'connection refused'.

```
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1 port 3000: Connection refused 
curl: (7) Failed to connect to backend port 3000: Connection refused
```

The port is EXPOSED in the Dockerfile but it's not even a problem since here i try to reach the port from inside the backend container (curl 127.0.0.1 or curl localhost) or from inside the
network in common to react and backend containers (curl http://backend:3000).

How can i resolve this?

I have tried to use the docker namespace instead of 127.0.0.1 or localhost and i get
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: docker
. I have tried not to expose the port (in Dockerfile and in docker-compose.yml). I have tried to set the docker driver to bridge but nothing works then.

Comment: i still wonder where the curl command is launched in docker exec -t backend curl http://127.0.0.1:3000 considered the docker daemon is in the dind service container. This could explain the origin of the request has to be configured in django allowed host and allowed cors...
Also, it seems impossible to find information on how ports are opened by gitlab shared runners regarding docker compose and the fact the docker daemon is in dind service container